# Python missing required positional arguments. Gives nonsense location

Tags: python, exception

I'm working on a little project in Python. I set up a class that needs to have multiple initializers for convenience. Python keeps telling me I'm missing positional arguments, but I don't call the initializer anywhere where I don't explicitly pass in the right number. I tried to replicate the problem in a smaller test case, but I can't get it to do the same thing. It's a bit of code, so it's hosted at :https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6568115

The error it gives is:

```
  File "./cards.py", line 40, in types
    if is_subset(types, self.__class__().VALID_TYPES):
TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'name', 'types', 'colors', 'land_type', and 'required_types'
```

Comment: Where is the `is_subset()` function? That's the call that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main errors:

1. `__class__` is a data member of any object (and contains the class of the object), calling a class object returns an instance so `self.__class__()` being the same as `(self.__class__)()` will try to create a new instance of the same class of `self`, but passing no arguments to constructor.
2. You are not programming in Python

The second error is the very big one and you should try to correct it as soon as possible.

In Python you write for example a 2d-point class as

```
class P2d:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

and not like

```
class P2d(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @x.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value
```

All this noise is not used in Python just for the fun of it (like Java for example does). You can just start simply with a data member and only later (and only when and **if really needed**) you can replace `x` with `_x` and getter/setter without needing to change anything in the users of your class.

A setter/getter pair that just sets and gets a data member is plain nonsense.

Writing Java using Python syntax is wrong for many different reasons. If you want to program in Java because you like to type and read a lot of boilerplate syntax then just use Java.

Comment: I've never done any serious programming in Java. I was using the setter to do "typechecking" on some of the values going in. I wasn't initially sure how I was going to do that though, and I just wrote getters and setters for everything to fill in later. You're right though, that I should go and delete the ones that are just doing assignment.

Answer (score 5):

`self.__class__()` is calling the initializer. Just use `self.__class__.VALID_TYPES` or even just `self.VALID_TYPES`

Comment: Interesting. My testing in the interpreter showed that the class method returns the class object, not an instance, which is surprising to me.

Comment: `__class__` is a instance variable, not a method.

Answer (score 2):

If the class name is Dog and d is an instance of Dog, then:

```
d.__class__()
```

is equivalent to:

```
(d.__class__)()
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(Dog)()
```

which is equivalent to:

```
Dog()
```

Similarly, you will learn that python methods are actually just functions inside a class, and the call:

```
d.bark()
```

is equivalent to:

```
(d.bark)()
```

which causes python to look up d.bark, and if a function is found in the Dog class, python converts the function to a method (an object that contains d, so that d can be passed to the method implicitly), and then python returns the method:

```
(method_obj)()
```

Then the trailing parentheses execute the method.

Comment: It doesn't look up `d.bark`, it just looks up `bark` and sends it an argument of `d` as self. the rest of the arguments come from the actual call.

Comment: _It doesn't look up d.bark_  You are mistaken.  The lookup path includes the instance, which is easy to prove. _it just looks up bark and sends it an argument of d_ No. bark is a function object which python then converts to a method object (bound or unbound) and the lookup returns the method object.

Comment: Never mind, you're right! I just tested it out in the interpreter by typing in `d.bark`. Turns out it's actually just a "bound method" added to the `Dog` class. This is cool, I'll give you +1 for explaining it to me. :) So wait, what is "self" then? Is it only a parameter for unbound methods? What happens when you do Dog.bark(d)???

Comment: self is just a _parameter variable_ name.  You can name it googly_googly if you want.  The method object that python returns contains the object that called the function, and when you execute the method, python automatically sends the calling object to the method.  If you don't catch it with a parameter variable, you will get an error.

Comment: Also you said "bark is a function object which python then converts to a method object (bound or unbound)". I understand what a bound method is, but what is an unbound method?

Comment: An unbound method is not bound to the calling object, so python can't automatically pass the calling object to the method....ergo Dog.bark(d).  Try `print Dog.bark'.  When you call the method with the class object, python does not create a bound method--python creates an unbound method.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to understand this a bit better now. Thank you.

Comment: _bound_ just means that the method object that python returns has the calling object inside it, and python will automatically pass the calling object to the method when it is executed.  _unbound_ means that the method object does not contain the calling object inside it, so python can't pass the calling object to the method when the method is executed.  Remember that `d.bark()` gets replaced by <bark_method>(), so unless <bark_method> has the calling object inside it, the calling object is gone.

Comment: In python, methods are really just attributes of the class object, so everything is an attribute.  Try `print Dog.__dict__`.  Also try: `def __init__(self): self.bark = "hello"`.  Which gets looked up first, the instance attribute bark or the method bark?  The lookup up path of d.bark is a bit complex and has several twists.

Comment: I tried the `self.bark = "hello"` thing along with defining a method called `bark`. The instance attribute got looked up before the method bark and when I tried calling `d.bark()` it could not find the method at all and it said 'str object is not callable'. That is some very interesting stuff :) Thank you for explaining this to me.